# When using findAll with BeautifulSoup it returns an empty list

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm practicing some web scraping and for this project I'm scraping this website: https://assetdash.com/?all=true

I'm getting and parsing the HTML code as following.

```
my_url = 'https://assetdash.com/?all=true'
client = urlopen(my_url)
page_html = client.read()
client.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.findAll("tr", {"class":"Table__Tr-sc-1pfmqa-5 gNrtPb"})
print(len(rows))
```

This returns a length of 0 whereas it should be returning a much higher value. Have I done something wrong with the parsing or am I retrieving the rows incorrectly?

Comment: Sure it does return an empty list because the entire site is behind `JS`, which means `BeautifulSoup` won't see a thing. Either check if there's an API you can query or explore `selenium`.

Comment: @baduker Oh okay, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It dynamic and javascript rendered. Go straight to the source of the data.

**Code:**

```
import requests
my_url = 'https://assetdash.herokuapp.com/assets?currentPage=1&perPage=200&typesOfAssets[]=Stock&typesOfAssets[]=ETF&typesOfAssets[]=Cryptocurrency'

data = requests.get(my_url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
       id ticker  ... peRatio  rank
0      60   AAPL  ...   35.17     1
1    2287   MSFT  ...   34.18     2
2     251   AMZN  ...   91.52     3
3    1527  GOOGL  ...   33.79     4
4    1276     FB  ...   31.09     5
..    ...    ...  ...     ...   ...
195   537  BMWYY  ...   15.06   196
196  3756    WBK  ...   35.57   197
197  1010     DG  ...   23.40   198
198  1711    HUM  ...   12.77   199
199  1194   EQNR  ...  -15.82   200

[200 rows x 13 columns]
```

Comment: How did you get that URL with the JSON file in it btw?

Comment: If you look at browser dev tools; network —> xhr

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks!